# Cross-platform (Android, iOS) game engines on Linux

Tags: cross-platform, game-development

I'm mostly experienced in Libgdx and Corona. Having tried unity gideros, and godot.

I'm currently on Linux so i can only use godot and Libgdx. Im tasked with creating a 2d game or 2.5d like catch the killer. A puzzle where you find hidden stuff, dialogue between characters and stuff like that. My boss is buying me a new laptop probably a mac so I can pick any Engine . Requirements are:

1. cross platform, Android ios
2. Internationalization and Localization
3. Ability for the user to download additional levels as he progresses or buy stuff
4. The final code should be small in size and the performance should be excellent, that's so important
5. The development time should be so fast because i have a tight deadline and i have a week to learn it.
6. Active community, well documented, many tutorials.

I would go for libgdx but not sure about 3, 4 and 5. if you have any other engine in mind let me know